# Is the Resource Server in OAuth a Web server or App server?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

The 'Resource Server' referred in the OAuth concept, would it be a Web server or App server ?

Answer (score 0):

Vague question get vague answers.

Yes and no and maybe both. 
There are many different architectures in use. (Some not so well done)

OAuth is a protocol for delegation of Authorization. Often the ONLY WEB server has a relationship with then end user and the App server only has a relationship with the WEB Server.

So one might use OpenID Connect for the user<->WEB Server relationship and OAuth for the WEB server<->App server.

As an example, assume you operate a Weather service. The user Authenticates to you WEB Server using OIDC. Now that the WEB server (ie OAuth Client) knows who the user is, it then uses OAuth to obtain the Weather from the (possibly third-party) App server. The App Server only needs to know the ZipCode for the user to get the weather and not require any Authentication of the end-user.

Let me know how I can help.